# Renaming Subdirectories To Different Date Format

Tags: shell, unix

In Ubuntu Linux:

I have a directory with many sub-directories. Each of those sub-directories has sub-directories whose names are in the date format:
M_D_YYYY

The problem is that when sorted alphabetically, they don't list in chronological order.

For example, 7_25_2019 lists before 7_3_2019 and even before 7_3_2018.

I want to rename the sub-directories into YYYY_MM_DD format, so that alphabetical order matches chronological order. So, in previous example, it will rename to:

2018_07_03

2019_07_03

2019_07_25

How is this best accomplished within a shell command or script?

NOTES:

(1) I want to rename the sub-directories only, not the files in them.

(2) I don't have control on the file structure at the time of the posting of the files via FTP. But, there is a break overnight. The ideal would be that after the first run "to fix the existing", that I could run a command/script (either the same or different) nightly (after midnight) that would leave the sub-directories named in the correct format and only modify the sub-directories (from the previous day) that are in the incorrect format.

(3) It is important that 1st level sub-directories that are not in a date format DO NOT get renamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all directories that meet your criteria (and that haven't been renamed) with a `find` invocation like this:

```
find -E . -type d -regex '.*/[1-9][0-9]?_[1-9][0-9]?_[12][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Having found the directories that need renaming, the next question is, how to rename them?

This is just tricky enough that it will be useful to encapsulate the functionality in an auxiliary script, which I'm going to call `renamedir`.  And once we have that script, we'll be able to invoke it on each directory using `find`'s `-exec` operator:

```
find -E . -type d -regex '.*/[1-9][0-9]?_[1-9][0-9]?_[12][0-9][0-9][0-9]' -exec renamedir {} \;
```

So what's inside the `renamedir` script?  My first cut at it isn't terribly elegant, but it works.  The best way to ensure that the month and day numbers are padded out to two digits is by using `printf`, I think.  But that means we need to break out the individual month, day, and year numbers into separate shell variables.  And I don't know of a nice, clean, portable way to do that, so what's here is rather brute force.  Anyway, here's my script:

```
path=`dirname "$1"`
dir=`basename "$1"`

m=`echo "$dir" | sed 's/^\([0-9][0-9]*\)_\([0-9][0-9]*\)_\([0-9][0-9]*\)$/\1/'`
d=`echo "$dir" | sed 's/^\([0-9][0-9]*\)_\([0-9][0-9]*\)_\([0-9][0-9]*\)$/\2/'`
y=`echo "$dir" | sed 's/^\([0-9][0-9]*\)_\([0-9][0-9]*\)_\([0-9][0-9]*\)$/\3/'`

if test $m -lt 1 -o $m -gt 12; then exit; fi
if test $d -lt 1 -o $d -gt 31; then exit; fi
if test $y -lt 1900 -o $y -gt 2100; then exit; fi

newdir=`printf "%d_%02d_%02d" $y $m $d`

mv "$path"/"$dir" "$path"/"$newdir"
```

(Obviously that's a sh script.  Perhaps the better approach would be to use Perl or Python.)

When I run this, I do get error messages like

```
find: ./tmp/7_25_2019: No such file or directory
```

These are because we're renaming directories out from under `find`, after it's found them but before it has a chance to descend down into them.  You can ignore those messages, I guess.  (If your m_d_yyyy directories ever contin m_d_yyyy subdirectories, this means you'll miss them, but they'll get found on the next run, so maybe that's okay.)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to respond. It works. That's all that matters for me. I just add ">& /dev/null" to the end of the command line and no error messages echo. I have added this to a daily cron that renames subdirectories and then moves them with rsync to their "permanent" place.